# Summing total of 1 column and subtracting if cell has value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So my boss asked me to make some Excel based timesheet in which employees kan record their worked hours. Everything is working fine, but I can't seem to figure out one thing. We are allowed to work overtime and can use these overtime hours for extra leave. Preferably in 1 cell I would like to show the total overtime, so the extra worked hours minus the hours I took from overtime for leave.

My workbook is built as follow:

- 1 column (named date) for the date
- 1 column (named activity) for the activity
- 1 column (named total) for the hours worked that date
- 1 column (named total_week) sums my daily hours to display the weekly hours
- 1 column (named tvt) subtracts my max weekly hours from my weekly hours to display my overtime per week
- 1 column (unnamed) sums my overtime to display the total overtime in 1 cell

I've tried serveal things but unfortunately haven't found the solution yet. I think It should be something like: SUM (tvt) and subtract value from (total) IF (activity) of that value equals to TVT. But I can't seem to figure it out. Anybody any solutions?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? What does activity column record ? When it records the time of  leaving,and it is column B, to get the extra worked time, we could use SUM(tvt) - SUMIF(B:B,"<>").

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot? I think a SUMIF formula or SUMIFS would work for this.

SUMIF will let you sum totals under one IF condition while SUMIFS will allow you to do so with several conditions. Either of these would pull in the total to one cell which would be what you are looking for.